# What will reduce the jittery behavior of tetrominoes pieces in this function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity tetrominoes game in C#. Each tetromino has a unique label or image and a unique proper landing place. If it lands in the wrong location, I'm using the following to move it to its proper destination before spawning the next piece:

```
void MoveMisplacedShapeToCorrectLocation(Shape shape, Vector3 vector3)
{
    float speed = 15;
    Vector3 targetPosition = m_gameBoard.m_dictionaryOfProperLocations[shape.name];
    Vector3 currentPosition = shape.transform.position;

    // First, check to see if the shape is close enough to the target
    if (Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, targetPosition) > .02f)
    {
        Vector3 directionOfTravel = targetPosition - currentPosition;

        // Normalize the direction, since we only want the direction information, not the magnitude.
        directionOfTravel.Normalize();

        // Scale the movement on each axis by the directionOfTravel vector components
        shape.transform.Translate(
            (directionOfTravel.x * speed * Time.deltaTime),
            (directionOfTravel.y * speed * Time.deltaTime),
            (directionOfTravel.z * speed * Time.deltaTime),
            Space.World);
    }
    else 
    {
        isMisplaced = false;
    }

}
```

In my update function, I have the following:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    PlayerInput();

    if (isMisplaced == true)
    {
        MoveMisplacedShapeToCorrectLocation(m_activeShape, transform.position);
    }
}
```

**This works fairly well, but some of the shapes jitter vigorously for up to a few seconds when they reach their proper place before settling in, whereas others settle as smoothly as if they snapped in**. I don't understand why. I've varied the speed and that doesn't seem to have much effect. I've also varied the distance (0.02 above) in the if-condition and that has some effect. But I want to keep that distance small (>= 0.03), otherwise when all the shapes are in their proper locations, too much looks "gap-toothed."

Is there anything that can be done to suppress the jitters?

**UPDATE as I've attempted to follow Ron's advice in the initial comment**:

Following Ron's advice in the initial comment below, here's what I've tried using Vector3.MoveTowards:

```
    void MoveMisplacedShapeToCorrectLocation(Shape shape)
{
    float speed = 15;
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // The step size is equal to speed times the frame time.

    Vector3 targetPosition = m_gameBoard.m_dictionaryOfProperLocations[shape.name];
    Vector3 currentPosition = shape.transform.position;

    // Check if the shape is unacceptably far from the target position:
    if (Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, targetPosition) > .02f)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Vector3.Distance");
        Debug.LogWarning(Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, targetPosition));
        Debug.LogWarning("step");
        Debug.LogWarning(step);
        // Move our position a step closer to the target.
        currentPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, targetPosition, step);
    }
    else 
    {
        isMisplaced = false;
    }

}
```

And I've slightly modified my update function to the following (I'm only using one parameter-argument pair rather than two now. In my initial post, the second parameter-argument pair were unneeded.):

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    PlayerInput();

    if (isMisplaced == true)
    {
        MoveMisplacedShapeToCorrectLocation(m_activeShape);
    }
}
```

**This is not working, however. The mis-landed shape just sits where it landed.** I would be grateful for you help. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that your translate overshoots the target position, then overshoots up, down, up, etc until the delta time somehow matches. You should be using [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) instead of Translate.

Comment: @Ron: I will try something with Vector3.MoveTowards. Thank you.

Comment: After this new modification, were there any improvements or notable differences?

Comment: @Ryolu: No, the mis-landed piece now just sits without moving at all.

Comment: maybe you could try  Vector3.SmoothDamp instead, like so  `currentPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currentPosition , targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);`

Comment: @Ryolu: Thanks. I'll try that and report back here, perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: @Ryolu: Thanks for alerting me to Vector3.SmoothDamp. Though I did not attempt to use it because I solved my problem with Vector3.MoveTowards, it is good to be aware of it.

Comment: @Ron: Yes, Vector3.MoveTowards worked much better than shape.transform.Translate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using Vector3.MoveTowards and without assigning shape.transform.position to a new variable "currentPosition" (contrary to the code I posted in the UPDATE to the original question above) as follows:

```
    void MoveMisplacedShapeToCorrectLocation(Shape shape)
{
    float speed = 10;
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // The step size is equal to speed times the frame time.

    Vector3 targetPosition = m_gameBoard.m_dictionaryOfProperLocations[shape.name];

    // Check if the shape is unacceptably far from the target position:
    if (Vector3.Distance(shape.transform.position, targetPosition) > .02f)
    {

        // Move our position a step closer to the target.
        shape.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(shape.transform.position, targetPosition, step);
    }
    else 
    {
        isMisplaced = false;
    }

}
```

and

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

PlayerInput();

if (isMisplaced == true)
    {
        MoveMisplacedShapeToCorrectLocation(m_activeShape);
    }
}
```

Thanks @Ron Beyer for your comment that sent me in the proper direction.